# python sql regex

Tags: python, regex

I am looking for a regex that finds each SQL (Oracle) statement with end ';'

e.g

SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM TEST;
ALTER TABLE TABLE_NAME add COLUMN_NAME NUMBER (1,0);
CREATE TALBE TABLE_NAME (TEST (1,9));
ALTER TALBE test.test 
ADD FLAG NUMBER (1,0)
ADD FLAG2 VARCHAR (10 CHAR)
ADD FLAG4 NUMBER (1,0);
```

so my regex is : `(\w+.*(?:\n*.*)*)` and idk how to end this with `;`

Comment: `\;` maybe? (iOS autocorrect has wrecked my comment)

Comment: There's no way to know where an SQL statement ends without an SQL parser.

Comment: So where's the question?

Comment: Are the SQL statements in a one big multiline string or are they separate string in a list? And yeah, please be more precise with the question.

Comment: What about [`\w[^;]*`](https://regex101.com/r/vI3sF5/3)

Comment: @bobblebubble Thank u its what i looking for

Comment: Thank u all for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this RegEx:

```
(\w+.*(?:;\n*.*)*;)
```

Check out the [Live Demo](http://regexr.com/3d1dp)

However, all SQL statements are meant to end with a `;`